# Associate newWizard with nature of selected project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rcp

I am trying to add a contribution to the `org.eclipse.ui.newWizards` extension point so that  the entry in the `new`-menu is only shown, when the selected project has a certain nature.

Is this possible only by declarative  use of this extension point?
I already look for an attribute like `<enabledwhen>`of a menu's action but the wizard's extension point does not seem to offer this possibility.

Any ideas to achieve the said behaviour is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported. New wizards always appear everywhere.

The only thing that can be controlled is the 'shortcuts' which appear in the top level of the New menu which can be configured according to the perspective using the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension point.

Answer (score 0):

Once new wizard "com.example.newWizard" is registered in a plugin "com.example.plugin" and shows in the New dialog, to add it to the context menu in the Proejct Explorer for project of "com.example.nature" nature, do the following:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent">
  <commonWizard
        associatedExtensionId="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resourceContent"
        type="new"
        wizardId="com.example.newWizard">
      <enablement>
         <with
               variable="selection">
            <count
                  value="1">
            </count>
            <iterate
                  ifEmpty="false"
                  operator="and">
               <and>
                  <adapt
                        type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
                  </adapt>
                  <test
                        property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature"
                        value="com.example.nature">
                  </test>
               </and>
            </iterate>
         </with>

      </enablement>
  </commonWizard>
</extension>
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.viewer">
  <viewerContentBinding
        viewerId="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer">
     <includes>
        <contentExtension
              pattern="com.example.plugin.*">
        </contentExtension>
     </includes>
  </viewerContentBinding>
</extension>
```

See [documentation](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_navigator_navigatorContent.html) for details.